# Is using java Map.containsKey() redundant when using map.get()

Tags: java, performance, code-readability, dictionary

I have been wondering for some time whether it is allowable within best practice to refrain from using the `containsKey()` method on `java.util.Map` and instead do a null check on the result from `get()`.

My rationale is that it seems redundant to do the lookup of the value twice - first for the `containsKey()` and then again for `get()`.

On the other hand it may be that most standard implementations of `Map` cache the last lookup or that the compiler can otherwise do away with the redundancy, and that for readability of the code it is preferable to maintain the `containsKey()` part.

I would much appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Some Map implementations are allowed to have null values, eg HashMap, in this case if `get(key)` returns `null` it does not guarantee that there is no entry in the map associated with this key.

So if you want to know if a map contains a key use `Map.containsKey`. If you simply need a value mapped to a key use `Map.get(key)`. If this map permits null values, then a return value of  null does not necessarily indicate that the map contains no mapping for the key; In such case `Map.containsKey` is useless and will affect performance. Moreover, in case of concurrent access to a map (eg `ConcurrentHashMap`), after you tested `Map.containsKey(key)` there is a chance that the entry will be removed by another thread before you call `Map.get(key)`.

Comment: Even if the value is set to `null`, do you want to treat that differently to a key/value which is not set?  If you don't specifically need to treat it differently, you can just use `get()`

Comment: If your `Map` is `private`, your class might be able to guarantee a `null` is never inserted in the map. In that case, you could use `get()` followed by a check for null instead of `containsKey()`. Doing so can be clearer, and perhaps a little more efficient, in some cases.

Answer (score 51):

I think it is fairly standard to write:

```
Object value = map.get(key);
if (value != null) {
    //do something with value
}
```

instead of

```
if (map.containsKey(key)) {
    Object value = map.get(key);
    //do something with value
}
```

It is not less readable and slightly more efficient so I don't see any reasons not to do it. Obviously **if your map can contain null, the two options don't have the same semantics**.

Answer (score 9):

As assylias indicated, this is a semantic question.  Generally, Map.get(x) == null is what you want, but there are cases where it is important to use containsKey.

One such case is a cache.  I once worked on a performance issue in a web app that was querying its database frequently looking for entities that didn't exist.  When I studied the caching code for that component, I realized it was querying the database if cache.get(key) == null.  If the database returned null (entity not found), we would cache that key -> null mapping.

Switching to containsKey solved the problem because a mapping to a null value actually meant something.  The key mapping to null had a different semantic meaning than the key not existing.

Comment: Interesting. Why didn't you simply add a null check before caching values?

Comment: That wouldn't change anything.  The point is that the key mapping to null means "we have already done this.  it's cached.  the value *is* null".  Versus not containing a given key at all, which means "Don't know, not in the cache, we may need to check the DB."

Comment: replacing containsKey with Map.get(x) == null condition is what fixed my sonar scan issue without breaking existing TCs too, so yea,thx.

Answer (score 7):

- `containsKey` followed by a `get` is redundant only if we know apriori that null values will never be permitted. If null values aren't valid, the invocation of `containsKey` has a non-trivial performance penalty and is just overhead as shown in the benchmark below.
- The Java 8 `Optional` idioms - `Optional.ofNullable(map.get(key)).ifPresent` or `Optional.ofNullable(map.get(key)).ifPresent` - incur a non-trivial overhead in comparison with just vanilla null checks.
- A `HashMap` uses a `O(1)` constant table lookup whereas a `TreeMap` uses a `O(log(n))` lookup. The `containsKey` followed by a `get` idiom is much slower when invoked on a `TreeMap`.

### Benchmarks

See https://github.com/vkarun/enum-reverse-lookup-table-jmh

```
// t1
static Type lookupTreeMapNotContainsKeyThrowGet(int t) {
  if (!lookupT.containsKey(t))
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown Multihash type: " + t);
  return lookupT.get(t);
}
// t2
static Type lookupTreeMapGetThrowIfNull(int t) {
  Type type = lookupT.get(t);
  if (type == null)
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown Multihash type: " + t);
  return type;
}
// t3
static Type lookupTreeMapGetOptionalOrElseThrow(int t) {
  return Optional.ofNullable(lookupT.get(t)).orElseThrow(() -> new 
      IllegalStateException("Unknown Multihash type: " + t));
}
// h1
static Type lookupHashMapNotContainsKeyThrowGet(int t) {
  if (!lookupH.containsKey(t))
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown Multihash type: " + t);
  return lookupH.get(t);
}
// h2
static Type lookupHashMapGetThrowIfNull(int t) {
  Type type = lookupH.get(t);
  if (type == null)
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown Multihash type: " + t);
  return type;
}
// h3
static Type lookupHashMapGetOptionalOrElseThrow(int t) {
  return Optional.ofNullable(lookupH.get(t)).orElseThrow(() -> new 
    IllegalStateException("Unknown Multihash type: " + t));
}
```

```
Benchmark                                (iterations)  (lookupApproach)  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units

MultihashTypeLookupBenchmark.testLookup          1000                t1  avgt    9  33.438 ± 4.514  us/op
MultihashTypeLookupBenchmark.testLookup          1000                t2  avgt    9  26.986 ± 0.405  us/op
MultihashTypeLookupBenchmark.testLookup          1000                t3  avgt    9  39.259 ± 1.306  us/op
MultihashTypeLookupBenchmark.testLookup          1000                h1  avgt    9  18.954 ± 0.414  us/op
MultihashTypeLookupBenchmark.testLookup          1000                h2  avgt    9  15.486 ± 0.395  us/op
MultihashTypeLookupBenchmark.testLookup          1000                h3  avgt    9  16.780 ± 0.719  us/op
```

#### TreeMap source reference

https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/TreeMap.java

#### HashMap source reference

https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java

Answer (score 6):

We can make @assylias answer more readable with Java8 Optional,

```
Optional.ofNullable(map.get(key)).ifPresent(value -> {
     //do something with value
};)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java if you check the implementation

```
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return getNode(hash(key), key) != null;
}

public V get(Object key) {
    Node<K,V> e;
    return (e = getNode(hash(key), key)) == null ? null : e.value;
}
```

both use getNode to retrieve the matching, where the main work gets done.

redundancy is contextual for example of if you have a dictionary stored in a hash map. When you want to retrieve the meaning of a word

doing...

```
if(dictionary.containsKey(word)) {
   return dictionary.get(word);
}
```

is redundant.

but if you want to check a word is valid or not based on the dictionary. 
doing...

```
 return dictionary.get(word) != null;
```

over...

```
 return dictionary.containsKey(word);
```

is redundant.

If you check [HashSet](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java) implementation, which uses HashMap internally, use 'containsKey' in 'contains' method.

```
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return map.containsKey(o);
    }
```