# Is Map.containsKey() useful?

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm wondering, does it make any sense to check for a particular key before trying to access it. Example:

```
Map myMap ....
if myMap.containsKey(key) {
   Object value = myMap.get(key);
   .....
}
```

Example of not using `containsKey`:

```
Object value = myMap.get(key);
if (value != null) {
 ......
}
```

EDIT: to clarify on null keys and values. Let's say, that map doesn't allow null keys and null values, so this two examples be identical.

Comment: Duplicated: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/14601016/1073063](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14601016/1073063)

Comment: This is both a duplicate **and** [not appropriate for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: @dhblah your edit makes your question a totally different question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes - keys can have `null` values:

```
Map myMap = ...;
myMap.put("foo", null);
if (myMap.containsKey("foo")) {
   Object value = myMap.get(key); // value is null
}

Object value = myMap.get("foo");
if (value != null) {
    // you won't get here
}
```

You could argue (and I'd agree) that not distinguishing a `null` value from a non-existent entry was a pretty bad design decision when they first made Java's collection API.

(Some maps - [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) and [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), at least - don't allow `null` values, which makes `containsKey` less important there, but it's still a nice readability improvement over `m.get(k) == null`.)

Answer (score 5):

In case your map allows for `null` values, with just `get(key)` you can't differentiate between key/value pair that has value = `null` and "no matching key/value pair exists".

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is useful - especially if your Map allows `null` values...

```
@Test
public void testContainsKey() {
    Map<String, Object> strObjMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    strObjMap.put("null", null);

    assertTrue(strObjMap.containsKey("null"));
    assertNull(strObjMap.get("null"));
}
```