# Why don't common Map implementations cache the result of Map.containsKey() for Map.get()

Tags: java, collections, guava, short-circuiting

A common pattern with a map is to check if a key exists and then act on the value only if it does, consider:

```
if(!map.containsKey(key)) {
  map.put(key, new DefaultValue());
}
return map.get(key);
```

However this is generally considered poor, as it requires two map lookups, where this alternative only requires one:

```
Value result = map.get(key);
if(result == null) 
{
  result = new DefaultValue();
  map.put(key,result);
}
return result;
```

Yet this second implementation has it's own problems.  In addition to being less concise and readable, it's potentially incorrect, as it cannot differentiate between the case where the key does not exist and where the key exists but maps explicitly to `null`.   In individual cases of course we can create external invariants that the map will not contain `null` values, however in general we cannot rely on this second pattern, needing to fall back to the less efficient implementation.

But why does the first implementation need to be less efficient?  `HashMap`'s `.containsKey()` looks like this:

```
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
  return getEntry(key) != null;
}
```

And Guava's `ImmutableMap.containsKey()` similarly is:

```
public boolean containsKey(@Nullable Object key) {
  return get(key) != null;
}
```

Since these calls go through all the work of doing a `.get()`, what is the disadvantage of caching the result of this call, and then short-circuting a successive call to `.get()` for the same key?  It seems like the cost is a single pointer, yet the benefit would mean the "right" way to implement such a pattern is also the "efficient" way to do so.

---

```
private transient Entry<K,V> lastContainsKeyResult = null;

public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
  lastContainsKeyResult = getEntry(key);
  return lastContainsKeyResult != null;
}

public V get(Object key) {
  if(key != null && lastContainsKeyResult != null && 
     key.equals(lastContainsKeyResult.getKey()) {
    return lastContainsKeyResult.getValue();
  }
  // normal hash lookup
}
```

Comment: What is this `DefaultValue`?

Comment: You'll have to synchronize the `containsKey` and `get` methods to work correctly in multi-threaded code.

Comment: You'd also need to add a dirty flag to indicate when the map has changed.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis just a dummy object, it shouldn't have any bearing on the question...

Comment: @Duncan very good point, that would be cause for concern.

Comment: Simple answer: Let the JVM (Hotspot optimizer) detect that the calculation is redundant and can be eliminated. This has the advantage of not wasting resources in the case it is not redundant. By the way, starting with Java 8 every `Map` supports `putIfAbsent` which addresses this use-case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because caching assumes a particular use-case but will actually slow things down in others. It also adds a lot of complications.

How do you cache the value? What happens when multiple threads are reading at once?

Sit down and start thinking through all the various edge cases and problems that can happen here. For example if the value gets changed between the contains call and the get call. Such a seemingly simple change actually introduced a lot of complexity and slows down a lot of operations which are actually more likely to be more frequently used than this specific sequence.

You should also consider that it's possible to build a "caching map" on top of a non-caching one but the opposite would not be possible.

Comment: Good point about the caching on top idea, after posting the question I thought a `CachedContainsMap` decorator might make sense; though it also would add it's own complexity and obtuseness to the code.

Answer (score 2):

Caching is helpful in some situation, detrimental in others. To implement caching within basic map implementations would cause problems in situations where caching is unhelpful.

Remember that one can easily construct a wrapper around a non-caching map that caches as appropriate for a particular scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's not worth it:

- Usually, you simply don't care.
- Your simple caching is not trivial at all as it needs to deal with modification and concurrency.
- In performance critical code you may write the ugly and fast workaround and avoid the overhead.
- *In another performance critical code you may need to call `contains` without the following `get` and your caching would slow it down.*

You can use this snippet which is always correct.

```
Value result = map.get(key);
if (result == null && !map.containsKey(key)) {
    // handle absent key
}
```

It uses only a single operation unless the `key` is absent or mapped to `null`. I guess, in your use case this doesn't occur often.

Answer (score 1):

The main points are covered by the other answers, but I want to address this point in particular:

> this second implementation has it's own problems. In addition to being less concise and readable, it's potentially incorrect, as it cannot differentiate between the case where the key does not exist and where the key exists but maps explicitly to null.

Something I took away with me from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14601074/2020801) answer (in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601016/is-using-java-map-containskey-redundant-when-using-map-get/14601074#comment20386829_14601074) comment) is the following: *Would you actually want to differentiate between* `null` *and an absent value?*

Although I can't speak in general terms, I would say that from my personal experience I have never needed to map keys explicitly to null.

A design where `null` is inserted into the map would, I speculate, mostly be used to indicate that a special/negative scenario has occurred. In such a case I would probably consider using the null object pattern instead by storing an actual object that through its method return values indicates to the caller that a special scenario has occurred.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly, but sadly unless the specification for Map is updated, utility code and the like has to account for this unfortunate possibility.

Comment: Not sure what you mean; `HashMap.get()` [supports both `null` keys and values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-).  Guava's `ImmutableMap` doesn't, which is fabulous, but I can't rely on that where code expects a `Map`.