# Dart: sort list of Strings by frequency

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to sort a list by frequency.

```
List myList = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "d", "d", "e"];
```

My expected output would be that the list is sorted on frequency & has no duplicated elements.

(myList has 3x "d" and 2x "e").

```
List output = ["d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "f"];
```

What's the most efficient way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

---

Is it also possible to do the same system with a List of Maps/Objects?

```
List myList2 = [{"letter": a, "info": myInfo}, {"letter": b, "info": myInfo}, ...]
```

Comment: first use `groupBy()`, then use `List.sort()`

Comment: To compare two objects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428735/how-do-i-compare-two-objects-to-see-if-they-are-the-same-instance-in-dart

Comment: `List myList = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "d", "d", "e"];
var out = groupBy(myList, (e) => e).values.toList()..sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
print(out);
print(out.map((e) => e[0]));`

Comment: Thanks @pskink, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not difficult to do that even without using `package:collection`.

```dart
List myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'd', 'd', 'e'];

// Put the number of letters in a map where the letters are the keys.
final map = <String, int>{};
for (final letter in myList) {
  map[letter] = map.containsKey(letter) ? map[letter] + 1 : 1;
}

// Sort the list of the map keys by the map values.
final output = map.keys.toList(growable: false);
output.sort((k1, k2) => map[k2].compareTo(map[k1]));

print(output);  // [d, e, a, b, c, f]
```

---

As for the second one, your desired output is unclear, but assuming that the values corresponding to the key `letter` are `String` and that you need exactly the same output as that of the first one, you can achieve it in a very similar way.

```dart
List myList2 = [
  {'letter': 'a', 'info': 'myInfo'},
  {'letter': 'b', 'info': 'myInfo'},
  {'letter': 'c', 'info': 'myInfo'},
  {'letter': 'd', 'info': 'myInfo'},
  {'letter': 'e', 'info': 'myInfo'},
  {'letter': 'f', 'info': 'myInfo'},
  {'letter': 'd', 'info': 'myInfo'},
  {'letter': 'd', 'info': 'myInfo'},
  {'letter': 'e', 'info': 'myInfo'},
];

final map2 = <String, int>{};
for (final m in myList2) {
  final letter = m['letter'];
  map2[letter] = map2.containsKey(letter) ? map2[letter] + 1 : 1;
}

final output2 = map2.keys.toList(growable: false);
output2.sort((k1, k2) => map2[k2].compareTo(map2[k1]));

print(output2);  // [d, e, a, b, c, f]
```

Comment: I actually overlooked the very important part mentioned by OP: `the most efficient way`, sorry. I'm curious which is more efficient with or without a package like `collection`, but either way, I believe the important thing is to measure the performance in your actual usage.

Comment: Using containsKey is unnecessary loop. As we have the target key we can check the nullability of it directly and enhance the performance. ```map[letter] = map[letter] != null ? map[letter] + 1 : 1 ```

Comment: @HamedHamedi Did you actually compare execution times? Using `containsKey()` on a map with 1,500 elements was more than 100 times faster than checking nullability on my PC. Can you show your evidence please? I wonder why `containsKey()` exists if it is really inefficient/unnecessary as you say. Is it only for better discoverability?

Comment: Its not about inefficiency. The thing is using right tool at right place. I described my reason and the evidence is the source code of dart http://astashov.s3.amazonaws.com/dartdoc_flutter/current/dart-collection/Maps/containsKey.html

Comment: Based on this [simple test](https://dartpad.dev/ed2447b329493dc16237014f3f544c52) , the performance for one million items are fairly equal but in some cases the `containsKey` takes longer and in rare cases it takes twice the time of null check. So we can conclude both implementation works well in real life use-cases, but I think this test is enough to give you the main idea. Also there is a [similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601016/is-using-java-map-containskey-redundant-when-using-map-get) in java which worth's checking

Comment: I found that the result turns around if the execution order is swapped in Hamed's code on DartPad. FYI, you can also use `Stopwatch` instead of `DateTime` for benchmarking.